# `np.arange` excepting error when stop=None but it giving unexpected result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am getting confused while using `np.arange` with only passing `start` like

```
np.arange(start=3, stop=None, step=None)
array([0, 1, 2])
```

I was expecting here `error` as end point is not define. but giving result i guess considering given `start` as `end` why?

---

---

Actually, I was trying `np.r_` with only passing `start` in slicing like

```
np.r_[3::]
```

Same here expecting `error` as end point not define but it lead me to `np.arange` As doc says [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

> If slice notation is used, the syntax `start:stop:step` is equivalent to `np.arange(start, stop, step)` inside of the brackets...

So i thought it similar to `np.arange(start=3, stop=None, step=None)`

Comment: this works the same as the built-in `range`, which is stated in the documentations, although, the exact behavior should probably be documented

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but the builtin `range` doesn't take kwds, so this particular accident can't happen.

Comment: @PaulPanzer granted. I agree, this is ambiguous documentation. Perhaps using the keyword arguments like this *should* throw an error, but the function hasn't been updated to use keyword-only/positional-only parameters which might allow that. EDIT: actually, probably, the ebst way would be to simply not allow keyword arguments

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga would certainly be the simplest, though it would in principle be possible to detect whether an argument was passed as keyword or positional, right? Do you happen to know what the overhead would be?

Comment: The docs `arange([start,] stop[, step,], dtype=None)`.  This is 'builtin', numpy's own compiled code. It processes the arguments directly.  It appears to ignore the keywords, just going by position.  The relevant code might be a decade old.  `start` and `stop` a clearly described as `optional`.  `stop` is required.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the part of `np.lib.index_tricks.AxisConcatenator` that handles the `slice` objects produced by the interpreter:

```
       if isinstance(item, slice):
            step = item.step
            start = item.start
            stop = item.stop
            if start is None:
                start = 0
            if step is None:
                step = 1
            if isinstance(step, complex):
                size = int(abs(step))
                newobj = linspace(start, stop, num=size)
            else:
                newobj = _nx.arange(start, stop, step)
```